# Memory cells organization and refresh time.

Tags: memory, refresh

A main memory unit with a capacity of 4 megabytes is built using 1M×1-bit
DRAM chips. Each DRAM chip has 1K rows of cells with 1K cells in each row. The
time taken for a single refresh operation is 100 nanoseconds. The time required
to perform one refresh operation on all the cells in the memory unit is ?

*This was asked in GATE 2010.*

Here is where I am stuck. How exactly is this memory organized? To get 4MB from 1Mx1-bit cells, we need 32 such cells. How are these 32 cells arranged to form 4MB of memory (specifically, how are they organized to rows and columns). I believe this is important to answer the above problem since during a refresh cycle, the entire row of memory gets refreshed at a time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each 1M  X 1 chip is organised as 1K  X 1K ie there are 1K rows.For constructing 4MB memory 32 chips are required .But all chips can be refreshed simultaneously.Chips are refreshed row wise.So total refresh time is 100*2^10 ns

Answer (score 0):

Its answer will be 3200*2^20 because in question they have asked the refresh time for all the cells and all cells combine and form a main memory of 4MB which is equal to 4*8*2^20bits = 32*2^20. Therefore the time required for refreshing is 32*2^20 * 100= 3200 * 2^20 ns..